# Can't access RowMatrix methods in PySpark: columnSimilarities(), computeColumnSummaryStatistics()

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to use the functions columnSimilarities(), computeColumnSummaryStatistics()

- Especially the columnSimilarities() function mentioned in this post:

> https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html

I am using a list of sparse Vectors from mlib.

```
sparse_vectors = []

for cust, group in df.groupby(0):

    i_v = zip(group[1].values, group[2].values)
    i_v = sorted(i_v)
    indices = [x[0] for x in i_v]
    values = [x[1] for x in i_v]
    sparse_vectors.append(Vectors.sparse(len(df[1].unique()), indices, values))

rows = sc.parallelize(sparse_vectors)
mat = RowMatrix(rows)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'RowMatrix' object has no attribute
>   'computeColumnSummaryStatistics'

or

> AttributeError: 'RowMatrix' object has no attribute
>   'columnSimilarities'

each time I run the functions.

Is this an issue of PySpark, as opposed to Scala Spark? I also can't find a page of RowMatrix functions through a google search as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access these methods because as for now (Spark 1.6) these are not implemented in PySpark.

`IndexedRowMatrix.columnSimilarities` (see [SPARK-12041](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12041)) is available in the current master but to use it you'll have to build Spark from source.

Comment: does this method only work with IndexedRowMatrix? Or is also available for RowMatrix?

Comment: Only `IndexedRowMatrix`, but it shouldn't be  hard to make this code work on `RowMatrix` as well.